# How do I find button that enabled timer

Tags: c#, winforms

I was wondering if it was possible to find which button enabled a timer in C#. Here's my code:

```
    private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        fadeIn_Timer.Start();
    }

    int a;

    private void fadeIn_Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var btn = (Button)sender;
        a += 30;
        if (a >= 255) {a = 255; }
        btn.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(a, 255, 255, 255); // would change back color of button1
        btn.Refresh();
        if (a == 255) { a = 0; fadeIn_Timer.Stop(); }
    }
```

I already tried `var btn = (Button)sender;`, but I don't seem to have any luck. If anyone can help me out that would be great!

Comment: What is `private void timer`?  It looks like a pseudo event you thought up yourself.

Comment: Its a timer that I'm trying to use for a fade in animation using the alpha of the back color from a button.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp: Actually it's a standard `Timer_Tick` event, perfectly valid. However the `sender` will be the `Timer` component.

Comment: Don't put tags in the title please.

Comment: I strongly suggest using indentation in your source code, it would make it a lot easier to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you save the `Button` in the `MouseEnter` event handler, then you have it for later. Something like this:

```
private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    fadeIn_Timer.Start();
    timerButton = (Button)sender;
}

int a;
Button timerButton;

private void fadeIn_Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    a += 30;
    if (a >= 255) {a = 255; }
    timerButton.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(a, 255, 255, 255); // would change back color of button1
    timerButton.Refresh();
    if (a == 255) { a = 0; fadeIn_Timer.Stop(); }
}
```

That should get you started.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know that it could have been that easy. Thank you very much for your answer, Poul Bak!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example for how you could implement this. The confusion is that Timer is a WinForms control but you need the System.Threading.Timer class for this to work.

So create a WinForms solution. Add a Form with a button (button1 in my case) and add the code below in the code behind of the form. When you click the button it should alternate it's background between black and white.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    System.Threading.Timer Timer { get; set; }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer = new System.Threading.Timer(button =>
        {
        Button myButton = (Button)button;

        if (myButton.BackColor == Color.Black)
            myButton.BackColor = Color.White;
        else
            myButton.BackColor = Color.Black;

        }, button1, 1000, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `System.Threading.Timer` event executes in a ThreadPool Thread...

Comment: @jimi What are you saying exactly?

Comment: That this - as it is - can only work in a small subset of scenarios. Settings the `BackColor` of a Button is one of these, because it just uses `RedrawWindow()` + `InvalidateRect()`: the first is Thread-agnostic, the second Thread-safe and the `object` value is taken from the PropertyStore. If you instead, try to change, e.g., the `Text` of this Button (or any other Control), then things change.

Comment: @Jimi: thanks for the headsup. Didn’t know that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the button object when you initiate the Timer like so:

```
        Timer = new Timer(someObjectThatWasPassed =>
        {
            // Code here can access 'someObjectThatWasPassed'
        }, someObjectToPass, 1000, 1000);
```

Make sure that 'Timer' is a field in your class i.e.:

```
        public class SomeClass
        {
            Timer Timer { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but I'm not to sure how to implement it into my code. I'm relatively new to C# and have updated my question to better explain what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Does your code compile?

Comment: @PaulSinnema I'm pretty sure OP talks about WinForms' Timer component, not a Timer that instantiated via code... but it is hard to know without [mre] (or at least clarification on what framework they are using).

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to mention that I am using winforms. Thank you @AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Ah, I think you're right. But he could still achieve this with a seperate timer in his code.